# Grouping data by multiply nested keys

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, chatbot

I have some input data:

```
data = [('15.05.2022 12:36', 46879, 'Clinton Bill', '555-55-55', 'USA, White House', 'Cond', 'id_1', '56', 10),
        ('15.05.2022 12:36', 46879, 'Clinton Bill', '555-55-55', 'USA, White House', 'Cond', 'id_1', '56', 1),
        ('15.05.2022 12:36', 46879, 'Clinton Bill', '555-55-55', 'USA, White House', 'Lub', 'id_2', '45', 5),
        ('15.05.2022 13:00', 33990, 'Monika L.', '666-66-66', 'USA, Pennsylvania Av', 'Cond', 'id_1', '56', 7),
        ('15.05.2022 13:00', 33990, 'Monika L.', '666-66-66', 'USA, Pennsylvania Av', 'Lub', 'id_2', '45', 3),
        ('15.05.2022 13:00', 33990, 'Monika L.', '666-66-66', 'USA, Pennsylvania Av', 'Lub', 'id_2', '45', 9)]
```

The row items are:

(date, user_id, user_name, user_phone, user_address, product_name, product_id, product_price, product_count)

I should group data by user_id to represent info about every **UNIQUE** user, where **count of the same products will be increminated**, using **python 3** script.

Smth like that:

```
output_data = [('15.05.2022 12:36', 46879, 'Clinton Bill', '555-55-55', 'USA, white house', ('Con', 'id_1', '56', 11), ('Lub','id_2', '45', 5)),
               ('15.05.2022 13:00', 33990, 'Monika L.', '666-66-66', 'Colorado', ('Con', 'id_1', '56', 7), ('Lub', 'id_2', '45', 12))]
```

*Or may be you will sugest some better ways of performing output data. I'm going to send it via bot to admins.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can group your data by unique ids and then calculate the product sum. Based on this output you can easily create your structure.

```
import collections
output_data = dict()

for date, user_id, user_name, user_phone, user_address, product_name, product_id, product_price, product_count in data:
    if not output_data.get(user_id):
        output_data[user_id] = collections.defaultdict(int)
    output_data[user_id][product_id] += product_count

print(output_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas style:

```
# convert your data to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
columns_minus_one = list(df.columns[:-1])

df2 = df.groupby(columns_minus_one , as_index=False).sum('product_count')
```

Output:

[image]

Then you can get back list:

```
df2.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) twice (first is to groupby customers, second is to groupby products) to get the desired output. Here is the code.

```py
import itertools
import operator

def my_groupby(lst, by_keys, return_keys):
    getter = operator.itemgetter(*by_keys)
    returner = operator.itemgetter(*return_keys)

    # If the data is not sorted, sort it by by_keys to make the groupby work properly
    sorted_data = sorted(lst, key=getter)
    it = itertools.groupby(sorted_data, key=getter)
    for key, subiter in it:
        # Yield the key as list and desired columns from the data
        yield list(key), [returner(item) for item in subiter]

res = my_groupby(data, by_keys=range(5), return_keys=range(5, 9))
output_data =[]

for customer in res:
    prod = list(my_groupby(customer[1], by_keys=range(3), return_keys=[3]))
    prod_total = list(map(lambda x: (*x[0], sum(x[1])), prod))
    output_data.append(customer[0] + prod_total)

print(output_data)
```

Output:

```
[['15.05.2022 12:36', 46879, 'Clinton Bill', '555-55-55', 'USA, White House', ('Cond', 'id_1', '56', 11), ('Lub', 'id_2', '45', 5)]
['15.05.2022 13:00', 33990, 'Monika L.', '666-66-66', 'USA, Pennsylvania Av', ('Cond', 'id_1', '56', 7), ('Lub', 'id_2', '45', 12)]]
```

The variable `res` has data grouped by customer details (column number 0 to 5) along with the products detail.

The next loop is to groupby the product details. `prod` will have product details and product counts. The total product counts were calculated using the `map` function. The calculated results were appended in an empty list, `output_data` to get the desired output.